# "Percent" Style Formatting in Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Have n sheets which have been selected and I am trying to apply the "percent' style to all for a range of cell selection. 
However only the  first sheet gets formatted. Other formatting styles that I am using work perfectly on all sheets. Only "percent" seems to be working only in the first sheet! Is there a specific reason for this? Pasting my Code snippet below: Thanks in advance for your help

```
Range(Cells(143, 2), Cells(146, MarketRangeColumn + 10)).Select
Selection.Style = "Percent"
Range(Cells(100, 2), Cells(142, MarketRangeColumn + 10)).Select
Selection.Style = "Comma"
Selection.numberformat = "_(* #,##0.0_);_(* (#,##0.0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
Selection.numberformat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
```

Comment: Are you creating multiple accounts?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413047/formatting-macro-doesnt-work-on-all-worksheets

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple sheets selected, applying a Style only affects the cells on the active sheet. Applying a NumberFormat will affect all sheets, so you should use that rather than the Style, or loop through each sheet.

Answer (score 0):

all sheets  selected method

```
Sub test()
    Dim vName()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, n As Integer
    For Each Ws In Worksheets
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vName(1 To n)
        vName(n) = Ws.Name
    Next Ws
    Sheets(vName).Select
    Range(Cells(143, 2), Cells(146, MarketRangeColumn + 10)).Select
    Selection.Style = "Percent"
    Range(Cells(100, 2), Cells(142, MarketRangeColumn + 10)).Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.0_);_(* (#,##0.0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
End Sub
```